# Lithium Ion Solar Battery Charger with current measurement

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, battery-charging, solar-cell, solar-charge-controller

I have designed battery operated device. The current consumption is around 4ma.
The battery which I use , is shown in following fig. the following schematic I have used to cutoff solar panel when battery gets full.

[image: solar charger schematic]

I have to measure current of solar panel.
As current is very small, how we can achive our purpose?
I have tried by using series shunt resistor, but it gives negative voltage with respect to ground.
Also  - for 1E R it give around 40mV.

[image: SOLAR CHARGER SCHEMATIC]

Comment: Please edit title to remove ALL CAPs.

Comment: Your FET will not work a desired. When it is off the body diode will still conduct. Reverse source and drain - it will still work as a switch (subject to a few other factors). || Charging using an eg TP4056 module will be much easier and probably cheaper. Note that battery MUST NOT be floated at 4.2V when fully charged - it must be turned off.